# Dealing with entities serialization in DDD

Tags: python, serialization, entity, domain-driven-design

I have a scenario in which an `Entity` defines an `EntityRepresentation` that is created from another end. The `EntityRepresentation` is a value object that implements some logic that should be performed on the other end after its transmission. In the end, the `EntityRepresentation` and `Entity` contains the same data but in the first case it is stored as a Python base type (string in my case), in fact the `EntityMapper` object is used to do the mapping between the two types in order to store the `Entity` mapped from the `EntityRepresentation`.

In other words, `EntityRepresentation` contains the same data as `Entity` but in a seriazable format that is determined by `Entity`. Since I'm trying to stick to a DDD I would know if what I'm doing is considered as anti-pattern. I'm a little skeptical about this design because I feel like I can stick with the `Entity` class only and the representation format could be handled by simply using a method on both ends. The fact is that this representation should not be stored along with the `Entity` props since it is subject to change in the future.

How correct would be let `Entity` provide a method to create a serializable representation of itself since my domain imposes a contraint on that?

Here is a sample code:

```
import json


class Entity:

    def __init__(self, id: str, name: str, type: str):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.type = type


class EntityRepresentation:

    def __init__(self, data: str = None):
        if data is None:
            d = {
                "id": "ID",
                "name": "NAME",
                "type": "TYPE"
            }
            self.data = json.dumps(d)
        else:
            self.data = data

    def process(self):
        # performs ops on self.data
        return True


class EntityMapper:

    def fromRepr(self, repr: EntityRepresentation) -> Entity:
        return json.loads(repr.data, object_hook=lambda r: Entity(**r))

    def toRepr(self, ent: Entity) -> EntityRepresentation:
        return EntityRepresentation(json.dumps(ent.__dict__))


def main():

    mapper = EntityMapper()

    # the representation is created on the first end
    e_repr = EntityRepresentation()

    # serialization
    e_repr_json = json.dumps(e_repr.data)

    # the json is sent into a wire
    # it is then received and deserialized on the other end
    e_repr_rec: EntityRepresentation = json.loads(
        json.loads(e_repr_json), object_hook=lambda d: EntityRepresentation(json.dumps(d)))

    if e_repr_rec.process():
        print(mapper.fromRepr(e_repr_rec))

    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your proposal looks OK to me, even if a little bit overkilled.

EntityRepresentation and EntityMapper classes are hardly coupled to Entity. So serialization and deserialization jobs could be Entity methods or raw functions.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
from typing import Any


class Entity:
    def __init__(self, id: str, name: str, type: str):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.type = type

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Entity {id(self)} {repr(self.__dict__)}"

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, data: dict) -> "Entity":
        return cls(data["id"], data["name"], data["type"])

    def to_dict(self) -> dict:
        return {**self.__dict__, "__class__": "Entity"}


class EntityEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o: Any) -> Any:
        if isinstance(o, Entity):
            return o.to_dict()
        return super().default(o)


def entity_decoder(obj: dict):
    if obj.get("__class__") == "Entity":
        return Entity.from_dict(obj)
    return obj


def main():

    # serialization & deserialization
    my_json = {
        "hello": "world",
        "my_entity": Entity("a", "b", "c"),
        "a_dict": {"hello": "earth"},
    }

    encoded = json.dumps(my_json, cls=EntityEncoder)
    decoded = json.loads(encoded, object_hook=entity_decoder)

    print("ORIGINAL:")
    pprint(my_json)
    print("SERIALIZED:")
    pprint(encoded)
    print("DESERIALIZED:")
    pprint(decoded)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: doesn't defining methods for serialization purposes in `Entity` goes against DDD?

Comment: It's OK to me. `from_dict` and `to_dict` method are just dict representation of the Entity. If those methods look weird to you, they can be move in the encoder / decoder parts. Then code will look like yours. Perhaps you will find it more "DDD compatible" but at the cost of lower pythonic code, IMHO.

This can be better decoupled by letting the EntityEncoder add the `__class__` key in the dict.